# jquery fade in images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fade in and out images with jquery but it's not working, I am missing something out.

see the script below:

```
var count = 1;
setInterval(function() {            
    count = (jQuery(".slideshow :nth-child("+count+")").fadeOut().next().length == 0) ? 1 : count+1;
    //alert (count);
    jQuery(".slideshow :nth-child("+count+")").fadeIn();
}, 2000);
```

And here is the HTML code.

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="hover">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <div class="mainportfo_title">title</div>
        </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="hover">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#" />
            <div class="mainportfo_title">title</div>
        </a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: `(...).fadeOut().next().length == 0` -- Also, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @JoffreyMaheo the `count+1` is actually correct.

Comment: i got the code from here http://jsfiddle.net/KA4Zq/ as you see there is no nested elements, all i want is to fade in and out images.

Comment: do you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/KA4Zq/611/

Comment: Do u want to have fade in and fade out effect on imgs on the go simultaneoudly or one after the other?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to target your `.hover` elements otherwise the `.nth-child` will select the wrong element.

```
var count = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    count = ($(".slideshow .hover:nth-child(" + count + ")").fadeOut().next().length == 0) ? 1 : count + 1;
    console.log(count);
    $(".slideshow .hover:nth-child(" + count + ")").fadeIn();
}, 2000);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6H6kE/)

Comment: Thank you @putvande can you help me to modify the code to crossfade ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery get() and works on this [**code**](http://jsfiddle.net/KA4Zq/613/), taht is definitely improvable:

```
var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    var target = $("img").get(i);
    var next = $("img").get(++i);
    $(target).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
        $(target).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
            $(next).fadeIn();
        }); 
    });
    if(i >= $("img").size()) {
        i = 0;
    }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

do you want to do this?: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3k9T/)

```
var count = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    count = (jQuery(".slideshow:nth-child("+count+")").fadeOut().next().length == 0) ? 1 : count+1;
    jQuery(".slideshow:nth-child("+count+")").fadeIn();
}, 2000);
```